# Chart.js HTML custom legend issues with doughnut chart

Tags: chart.js, legend

I'm working with chart.js and I followed [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5070) to create a custom HTML legend.
The thing is, the hide/show functionality is not working. The first legend click hides the whole chart, while the others produce the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined
    at t.getDatasetMeta (Chart.min.self-b26766dbef822c075056eb7012dc36ae75970dc990497732f927d46ef6070858.js:11)
    at HTMLLIElement.legendClickCallback (plot.self-416475a747a420b91c7fab454c07846f1043f55cc28f6d810fafeab61c56cf01.js:317)
```

so it traces back to t.getDatasetMeta. 
I gotta say it's working great with line/bar charts, so its only my doughnut chart which breaks.
Let me know if you need more info.
Oh and thanks :P

EDIT: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0tpfL8j/244/)

Comment: Any chance you could add a JSfiddle showing this? It is a lot of code to have to replicate by hande.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0tpfL8j/244/

Notice the first legend hides the whole chart, the rest produce the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you have only one dataset and your code use the `index` of legend item clicked to hide `datasets[index]`.

On the contrary you need to hide single item data as below:

```
var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
var item = meta.data[index];
```

Check the fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/aa2n39s2/

Comment: Amazing. I suspected the problem was something like that since only the first index worked. Thank you very much @beaver ! much appreciated.