# Way to show only legend rectangle and not the text in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

Is there a way to show only the rectangle of legend and not show the text next to it. I have looked everywhere but couldn't find a solution

Comment: You can use custom [html-legends](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#html-legends), as in my posts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154674/chart-js-html-custom-legend-issues-with-doughnut-chart/48165753#48165753, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751114/displaying-mixed-types-of-legends-bar-and-lines-with-chartjs/48762228#48762228; obviously you have to remove text legend from my examples